# Como fazer para quando clicar no botão executar ação a cada 1 segundo

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou utilizando o CefSharp e queria que quando clicasse no botão executa o `javascript` a cada 1 segundo e em segundo plano também, e só parasse se clicasse no botão desligar. Tentei pelo backgroundworker mas não consegui, sou meio leigo nessa parte:

Quando clica no botão executa o background worker:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bool rodando = true;

    chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$(document).ready(function(){if($('#signup_button').is(':visible')){alert('Você precisa estar logado para utilizar o script')}})");

    try
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => 
        {
            while (rodando)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Script();
            }
        });

        t.Start();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Botão de desligar:

```
private void btnscriptshutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        worker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Só que não está fazendo o loop, só executa uma vez, como posso fazer para executar sempre?

Comment: Ainda com problemas nesse código?

Comment: Sim só que estou fazendo pelo botão agora, sem o background worker

Comment: Poderia tentar através de um Timer..

Comment: Como ficaria para ficar executando até clicar num botão para parar?

Comment: Vou colocar o código, me dá um tempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar um `BackgroundWorker`, você pode utilizar um `Timer`, da biblioteca `System.Timers.Timer`.

Seu código pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Botão para iniciar a thread
    btnStart.Click += Start_Click;

    // Botão para encerrar a thread
    btnStop.Click += Stop_Click;
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cria e inicia o timer para ser disparado a cada 1 segundo = (1000 ms)
    if (_timer == null)
    {
        chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$(document).ready(function(){if($('#signup_button').is(':visible')){alert('Você precisa estar logado para utilizar o script')}})");

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Já existe uma tarefa em andamento!");
    }
}

private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Encerra o timer, se estiver ativo
    if (_timer != null && _timer.Enabled)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _timer = null;
    }
}

// Código executado a cada 1 segundo
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Script();
}
```

Neste exemplo, o `Form` tem dois botões: o `btnStart` que inicia a `thread` e o `btnStop`, que pára a `thread`.

O método `Timer_Elapsed` é o responsável por ficar executando o seu código a cada 1 segundo.

**Importante**

Como agora o seu código está executando em uma thread separada da thread principal, caso seja necessário atualizar qualquer informação na tela, como por exemplo o texto de `Label`, você deve executar o respectivo código na `thread` principal, utilizando `Invoke`.

**Exemplo**

```
lblSeconds.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    lblSeconds.Text = "Label atualizado a partir de outra thread.";
}));
```

Comment: Uma pergunta, como posso fazer se tipo o CefSharp executa um javascript ai esse código javascript está assim: alert('teste'); como faço para parar o timer? Porque fica aparecendo alert a cada 1 segundo e não tem como clicar no botão STOP

Comment: Tu pode criar uma lógica para iniciar o timer apenas se o usuário tiver logado.